# Enabling Google API - QPX Express

Tags: google-api, google-qpx-express-api

I am having some trouble enabling the Google API - QPX express. Does anyone know if this app is still supported?

When I navigate to:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/qpxExpress.googleapis.com/overview?

[image]

I am pretty sure I have access, since I am logged into my project and have access to other apis. Any ideas?

Comment: same problem here, Google should update their documentation, they've become lazy about it nowadays.